# Concatenar colunas e retornar a relação pelo SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Suponha que eu tenha as seguintes tabelas e suas relações:

```
Tabela A
    Col 1
    Col 2
    Col 3

Tabela B
    Col 1
    Col 2
    Col 3

Tabela C
    Col 1
    Col 2
    Col 3

Tabela D
    Col 1
    Col 2
    Col 3


Relacionamentos:

A (col 1) ---> B (col 1)  ---> C(col 1)
```

As tabelas A, B e C estão relacionadas através da 1º Coluna.

```
SELECT 

       Tabela A.Col 2,
       Tabela A.Col 3,
       Tabela B.Col 2,
       Tabela C.Col 3

       FROM Tabela A, Tabela B, Tabela C 

       WHERE Tabela A.Col 1 = Tabela B.Col 1    and     Tabela B.Col 1 = Tabela C.Col 1
```

Com o código acima conseguiria parcialmente buscar o que preciso. Agora, o que pretendo é concatenar a col 2 e a col 3 da Tabela D para conseguir fazer a relação entre B(col 1) --- D(col 2 & col 3) e, posteriormente, puxar a col 1 da Tabela D. É possível fazer isso? Se sim, como?

A Tabela Final ficaria assim:

```
Tabela All:
       A.Col 2,
       A.Col 3,
       B.Col 2,
       C.Col 3,
       D.Col 1
```

Answer (score 5):

Select simples:

```
    select * 
      from Tabela A
     inner join Tabela B on A.Col1 = B.Col1
     inner join Tabela C on A.Col1 = C.Col1
      left join Tabela D on B.Col1 = D.Col2+D.Col3
```

Utilizei aqui o left join para a tabela D por entender que é uma chave composta e pode não trazer resultados necessários para o join.
Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 2):

Bom, achei um pouco confusa a explicação. Mas na teoria se você fizer join entre as 4 tabelas, você pode colocar qualquer informação no seu select. O código abaixo te atende?

```
   SELECT 
        A.Col 2,
        A.Col 3,
        B.Col 2,
        C.Col 3,
        D.Col 1
   FROM 
       Tabela A
       INNER JOIN Tabela B ON (B.Col1 = A.Col1)
       INNER JOIN Tabela C ON (C.Col1 = A.Col1)
       INNER JOIN Tabela D ON (D.Col1 = A.Col1)
```

Comment: Ele quer pegar a coluna 1 da tabela D junto com as demais já descritas, mas para isso ele tem que concatenar as colunas 2 e 3 da tabela D para relacionar com a coluna 1 da tabela B e conseguir uma relação entre as tabelas. Sua resposta ainda não atende completamente.

Comment: A última linha seria algo do tipo: `INNER JOIN Tabela D ON ((concatenação de D.Col2 com D.Col3) = B.Col1)`. Não sei como concatenar duas colunas em SQL, mas falta isso pra resolver, acredito.